# How to remove or hide empty row based on sorting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I am working on table I want to hide or remove the row if there is no data on that particular column when I am clicking sort on "**Debit**" or "**Credit**". For example if the user loads the app intially there will not be any sorting applied. Once user clicks the debit column first time I am doing **ASC order** sorting for second time I am doing **DESC order** sorting. I am trying to hide the row if there is no value is there in **Debit Column** once after the sorting. I have tried using remove , but I didn't get the expected result. Could anyone guide me to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Below is my code:

```
let data = [
      {
        i: 1,
        visitiedDate: "2021-04-02",
        visittype: 1,
        debit: ,
        credit: 100,
        oustanding: 1000,
        allbal: 1000,
      },
      {
        i: 2,
        visitiedDate: "2021-04-02",
        visitorCode: ["ABC002"],
        visittype: 1,
        debit: 800,
        credit: 100,
        oustanding: 1000,
        allbal: 1000,
      },
      {
        i: 3,
        visitiedDate: "2021-02-02",
        visitorCode: ["ABC003"],
        visittype: 2,
        debit: 800,
        credit: 100,
        oustanding: 1000,
        allbal: 1000,
      },
      {
        i: 4,
        visitiedDate: "2021-02-01",
        visitorCode: ["ABC004"],
        visittype: 2,
        debit: 900,
        credit: 100,
        oustanding: 1000,
        allbal: 1000,
      },
      {
        i: 5,
        visitiedDate: "2021-03-01",
        visitorCode: ["ABC005"],
        visittype: 2,
        debit: ,
        credit: 100,
        oustanding: 1000,
        allbal: 1000,
      },
      {
        i: 6,
        visitiedDate: "2021-04-02",
        visitorCode: ["ABC006"],
        visittype: 1,
        debit: 500,
        credit: 100,
        oustanding: 1000,
        allbal: 1000,
      },
    ];

const columns = [{
    "key": "visitiedDate",
    "name": "Date",
    "isSort": true
  },
  {
    "key": "visittype",
    "name": "Type",
    "isSort": true
  },

  {
    "key": "credit",
    "name": "CAmount",
    "isSort": true
  },
  {
    "key": "debit",
    "name": "DAmount",
    "isSort": true
  },

  {
    "key": "oustanding",
    "name": "CBal",
  },
  {
    "key": "allbal",
    "name": "DBal",
  },
]

    

const [col, setCol] = useState(columns)
cosnt rows = data
    
function SortedRows(rows, col, sortMethod){
    
    const soredtRows = (( sortMethod === "ASC") || (sortMethod === "DESC")) && ((columns === "debit") || ((columns === "credit"))) ?
    rows.map((details) => {
        if (details.debit === ""){
            return (details.debit).remove()
        }
        else {
            return Object.assign({}, details, {oustanding:"", allbal:""})
        }
    })
    :
    rows
    
    return sortMethod
    ? sortedRows
    .slice()
    .sort(
    ({[columns]:a}, {[columns]:b}) => 
        (a === b ? 0 : a<b ? -1 : 1) *
        (sortMethod === "ASC" ? 1 : -1)
    )
}
const rows = col
  .slice()
  .reverse()
  .reduce(
    (sortedRows, {
      key: col,
      isSort,
      sortMethod
    }) =>
    isSort ? SortingRow(sortedRows, col, sortMethod) : sortedRows,
  );
```

Comment: As a random hint, it's probably better to do any data shaping on the backend. Things like sort, filter and pagination. The frontend should be a lightweight view layer, not do much number crunching. Backend or even database is more suited for that. Filtering on the frontend is almost a code smell, IMO.

Comment: Also keep in mind that when you want to delete items from a list, you should iterate from the end to the start. Because when you remove items, you will mess up the indices but when you go backwards you are safe.

Comment: sure , will keep track on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to call remove on it. You have two ways to solve this.

1. Return `null` instead of `(details.debit).remove()`
2. Apply a `filter` to `rows` before `map`

```
rows.filter(row => row.debit !== "").map(/* your logic */)
```

(notice the `filter` will return all those rows which are **not** empty)

Comment: I have tried adding above logic like below 

rows.filter(row => row.debit !== "").map((details) => {
 return Object.assign({}, details, {oustanding:"", allbal:""})
}
 but I am geting all the rows , can you highlight me where I went wrong

Comment: Can you share a codesandbox link? Most of your code is invalid. It would help if you can share minimumr reproduceable code